# Writing XML in Python using SAX

Tags: java, python, xml, saxparser

Looking at the [Python SAX documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) I only see **reading** XML using SAX. But I would like to **write** it.
 I figured out how [to do that in Java](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8B3G7U) a while ago:

```
 public void renderXML(OutputStream out) {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
      StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(pw);
      SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      TransformerHandler hd = tf.newTransformerHandler();
      Transformer serializer = hd.getTransformer();
      serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
      serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml");
      serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); // So it looks pretty in VI
      hd.setResult(streamResult);
      hd.startDocument();
      AttributesImpl atts = new AttributesImpl();
      atts.addAttribute("", "", "someattribute", "CDATA", "test");
      atts.addAttribute("", "", "moreattributes", "CDATA", "test2");
      hd.startElement("", "", "MyTag", atts);
      String curTitle = "Something inside a tag";
      hd.characters(curTitle.toCharArray(), 0, curTitle.length());
      hd.endElement("", "", "MyTag");
      hd.endDocument();
   }
```

What would be the Python equivalent? I checked an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737244/generate-xml-with-sax2-in-python/4737362#4737362) using ElementTree - but that is rather the DOM way to do things (and problematic for really large output). [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502503/how-to-stream-xml-output-quickly-from-python) is un-answered. Or: what is the better approach writing out XML in Python?

Comment: For very large XML, an _not_so_elegant_but_working solution is using a template engine (like Cheetah for example: http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html and for an example of Bible in [OSIS XML](https://www.crosswire.org/osis/) take a look at [this script](https://gitlab.com/bible_sword/CzeKMS/blob/d7bc1a3a5cdcc136a3d40bff7426a9f8fc181771/CEPtoOSIS.py).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct SAX-like way in Python; but I wrote a library for this that might perhaps be useful to you. It provides methods to open and close elements, make pis, comments, doctypes, etc. It has a fair range of higher-level features, like keeping track of what elements and inherited xml:lang values (if any) are in play, doing all the escaping for you (even %xx escaping for URIs in attributes), and things like "closeToElement(type)" etc. I find it makes it much easier to produce WF XML from Python. At http://www.derose.net/steve/utilities/PY/XmlOutput.py if interested.